# Drools template to substitute object property won't work

Tags: jboss, drools, mvel

Context :
I'm trying to write a jboss drools template that tests the value of an object whether is null or empty or a valid one.

The property holding the value is a variable depending on $pitCaract value

exemple if `$pitCaract=='C' => $valueProperty=valeurItemChaine`

so in my template I wanted to test on `itemDataCheck.valeurItemChaine`

here is what I have tried so far

```
    template header
    $pitCaract
    $valueProperty


    package fr.xxx.validation;
    /*created on: Jun 20, 2017*/
    import fr.xxx.fides.dashboard.questionnaire.api.models.items.ItemData;
    import fr.xxx.fides.dashboard.questionnaire.api.models.types.Item;
    import  fr.xxx.fides.dashboard.questionnaire.api.checks.QuestionnaireItemException;
    import fr.xxx.fides.dashboard.questionnaire.api.ExceptionMessage;

    template "Blocking Objects check"

    rule "pre-check of blocking @{$pitCaract}  @{row.rowNumber}"
    auto-focus true
    agenda-group "validate"
    dialect "mvel" 
    salience 100
        when
            $item: Item(
                        itemProperty.pitCaract== "@{$pitCaract}",   
                        itemProperty.isMandatory
                    )

            Boolean(booleanValue ==true ) from  nullOrEmptyStr($item.itemDataCheck.@{$valueProperty} )
---------------------------------------------------------------^ this line
        then
          $item.setQuestionnaireItemException(new QuestionnaireItemException(ExceptionMessage.Blocking_item ,QuestionnaireItemException.ERROR ) );
          delete($item);
    end

    end template


    function boolean nullOrEmptyStr(Object o)
    {
        System.out.println("nullOrEmptyStr:"+o);
        return o==null || o.toString().trim().isEmpty();
    }
```

I get an error message of kind

> [Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode:
>   java.lang.Object.valeurItemChaine()] [Near : {... nullOrEmptyStr(
>   $item.itemDataCheck.valeurItemChaine ) ....}]

I have tried

```
$item: Item(
                            itemProperty.pitCaract== "@{$pitCaract}",   
itemDataCheck!.@{$valueProperty}.toString().trim().isEmpty(),
                            itemProperty.isMandatory
                        )
```

and

```
$item: Item(
                                itemProperty.pitCaract== "@{$pitCaract}",   
    nullOrEmptyStr(itemDataCheck!.@{$valueProperty}),
                                itemProperty.isMandatory
                            )
```

But no luck getting this to work.

the only working solution is `itemDataCheck.@{$valueProperty}==null` but this not sufficient as the value could be an empty string.

Thanks for help

Comment: How are Item.itemDataCheck and its class defined?

Comment: @laune thay are Simple POJOs , Item has a member called itemDataCheck

Comment: Please provide the code how this is written, only the members in question.